# What phosphorescence material emits light for a 1 hour period?

Tags: spectroscopy, materials-design, experimental, photochemistry

I am looking for a phosphorescence material that emits light (400nm - 600nm). The trick is I need the material not to heat up when absorbing or discharging the light, so basically, I hope it maintains room temperature. Furthermore, I am hoping it can maintain emitting light for a period of (20 min - 3 hours).

Is there any commercial material as such or anything similar?

Comment: I am going to vote to close, I will point you towards strontium aluminates, they can emit in the right region of light and can emit for quite a long time.  They are common in glow in the dark commercial materials.  This is not the right SE to ask on though, you should try chemistry or physics.  Welcome either way, maybe we can help with other questions :)

Comment: @Tristan why not just write the strontium aluminates suggestion in an answer :)

Comment: @NikeDattani Because without more information, it is hard to say that writing a real answer to this question is worthwhile to anyone in the future.  This seems oddly specific and I only know they emit in the right region for a while.  We should move this question, even if we could technically answer it.

Comment: @TristanMaxson Let's continue this discussion at [General Chat Room for Matter Modeling Meta](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113019/general-chat-room-for-matter-modeling-meta).

Comment: @TristanMaxson Do you know if the powder heat up when it lights up in the dark?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Strontium aluminate can be doped with europium to give a material with properties like you are expecting.  This can be optimized to give maximum fluorescent yield as well, but keep in mind this will likely shift the wavelength.

The material must heat and cool in this process since absorption of light will not be 100% efficient and neither will the loss of light (some light may be emitted towards the material rather than outwards.).  Most heat production should occur during the "charging" phase of the cycle though since the heat produced will be due to the transition from high energy levels to lower but still excited energy levels by vibrational loss of energy.

I am unsure what your application is, but [here is a paper](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/jp022062c) on the synthesis of these materials.